# SSMS View editor keeps removing '[' and ']' from server specification?

Tags: sql-server, view, specifications, ssms-2017

I have linked from one SQL Server to a remote SQL Server from within SSMS and from a new Query window can now successfully select data from the remote server using SQL like this;

```
SELECT * FROM [Server\Instance].Database.dbo.Table
```

But when I paste the above SQL into a View, SSMS removes the '[' and ']' from the server specification to give;

```
SELECT * FROM Server\Instance.Database.dbo.Table
```

and then returns the error: "Incorrect syntax near '\'".

How can I stop SSMS from removing the '[' and ']'?

I have overcome this problem before but cannot remember how!
I even have working examples of Views but do not know how they retain their braces?

If there is a setting in Tools, Options I cannot find it.
If there is a setting in the View definition I cannot find it :-(

Any help appreciated,

Cheers,
Mal.

Answer (score 0):

I phoned a friend who suggested creating the view in this way;

`CREATE VIEW [MyView] AS SELECT * FROM [Server\Instance].Database.dbo.Table`

I could then successfully select from the view with;

`SELECT * FROM [MyView]`

I have not tried opening the view in the editor in case it strips the '[' and ']' out.

Mal.